# Sobol numbers in monte Carlo simulation

Tags: options, r, monte-carlo, simulations

I wanted to figure how how much faster the Sobol quasi random numbers convergence to the B&S call price compared with pseudo random numbers. To generate the Sobol numbers I used the randtoolbox in R to generate these numbers. When using just one step, so from t=0 to t=T, it’s easy. I used the following formula to go from s(0) to s(T).

S_t= S_0*exp⁡((μ- σ^2/2)*t+ σW_t,   where W_t  is a Sobol Random Number

I use the Sobol numbers and therefore the convergence is much faster because these numbers are better normal distributed when using pseudo random numbers.

My problem is the following:

How do I need to generate these numbers if I use intermediate steps in my simulation, do I need to use more dimensions or just generate more Sobol numbers from the same numbers. I’m already stuck for a long time on this. Hopefully somebody can help me, especially using the randtoolbox package from R to generate these numbers.

Thanks

Comment: I have a very detailed chapter on this in More Mathematical Finance as Mathias Korner already pointed out. You have to be really careful when you use Sobol. Treating them like pseudo-randoms is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 2):

First let me say that in the Black-Scholes model as you have it, there is of course no need for intermediate steps when pricing vanilla calls, since the SDE has the closed-form solution you included.  Intermediate steps would be required for complicated payoffs or other SDEs.

To answer your question though, you *do* need to use additional dimensions.  Think of the option pricing algorithm as an integration over the probability space of stock price paths.  Each intermediate tenor introduces a new dimension to that probability space.

The *point* of these quasirandom sequences is that, in multiple dimensions, they provide more evenly-distributed coverage of the probability space than pseudorandom numbers would give us.

**Quasirandom**

[image: Quasirandom sampling in 2D]

If we don't make multidimensional draws from the Sobol sequence, we would not benefit from that extra regularity.

**Pseudorandom**

[image: Pseudorandom sampling in 2D]

Note how these pseudorandom draws have multiple spots where samples are right next to each other, along with some very big "holes".

Answer (score 1):

You need to use more dimensions. If the number of dimensions (i.e. steps) is large, you may also have to use a Brownian bridge as described in the book by [Joshi](http://www.markjoshi.com/more/) or [Jäckel](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-047149741X.html).